# Issue with word-break:break-word;word-break:break-all

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have 3 buttons in my cshtml page. Every button opens up a popup having a kendo grid. 
I have implemented CSS styling to display data in the grid in wrapped format. For that, I have used the below code:

```
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("gridEMailDistList")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;word-break:break-word;word-break:break-all;" })
```

The grid works fine and shows data in wrapped format. The issue occurs when I click on another button which opens some other popup (having another kendo grid) and close it, and re-click on my first button. The grid present in the first popup doesn't show the data in wrapped format anymore!! 
Can you please tell me what went wrong??

Comment: You're overwriting `word-break:break-word` with `word-break:break-all`, although I don't think that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Did you show the source of your second popup and checked if there is a css code for word-break marked ! important ?

Comment: A better approach would be to add css for all the grids. For ex. <style>
    `.k-grid td {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>`